# Can a .NET application read certificates from local file system instead of windows keystore

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to read certificates from .p12 file and use them for an SSL/TLS communication while using SSLStreams?

```
sslstream.AuthenticateAsClient(SERVERNAME, ReadCertificates(), sslProtocol, sslCertRevocationCheck);

 private X509Certificate2Collection ReadCertificates()
    {
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = null;
        X509Certificate2Collection collection2 = null;
        try
        {
            String certStore1 = "C:\\Temp\\Certs\\Client.p12";
            X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(certStore1, "*****");

            //Create a collection and add two of the certificates.
            collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            collection.Import(certStore1,"*****",X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
            collection2 = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
            {
                if(cert.HasPrivateKey)
                    collection2.Add(cert);
            }                
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Certificate collection:" + collection.Count);
        return collection2;
    }
```

The above code fails with the following exception

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

The code works only if the public key of the server is put into the Windows keystore.
Client.p12 contains both the client's private key and the server's public key.

Comment: The [`X509Certificate2` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=net-6.0) can take a byte array or a filename, so I don't see what the issue is. What have you tried?

Comment: @Charlieface As part of my testing what i observed is if the server's public key isn't stored in the Windows keystore then the client application fails.

Comment: You need the public key and private key in the same file in order to load it into `X509Certificate2`. Please show your current code as a [mcve]

Comment: @Charlieface: I had added the sample. Client.p12 contains both the public key of the server and the client's private key. Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong here

Comment: `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` means the problem is with TRUST of the remote server certificate, NOT the certificate you loaded from disk.

Comment: *"Client.p12 contains both the client's private key and the server's public key."* it needs the client's public key not the server's. Also why are you creating a collection then looping through it and adding to a second one, why not just use the first collection?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET6 the above can be achieved using [AuthenticateAsClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclient?view=net-6.0#system-net-security-sslstream-authenticateasclient(system-net-security-sslclientauthenticationoptions)) with [SslClientAuthenticationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslclientauthenticationoptions?view=net-6.0) and set RemoteCertificateValidationCallback